# What are some of the oddest filenames in your library?

Tags: library, file-naming

Some of my classics:

- Hen attack
- Cabbage bat
- Bunny guts
- Mud hammer
- Wind by Sandyface
- Gut slides

all very meaningful (to me at least)

Answer (score 2):

I have a favorite:

- Fat Lady Walla

Answer (score 1):

my favourite is - Rug dipped in lake

Answer (score 1):

I think my strangest is:

ghetto hooker

Answer (score 1):

These track listings from commercial libraries made me laugh (im easily amused)

- digi i7 - 99 - HUMAN - FALLING IN TO SHRUBBERY -  FALLING IN TO BUSH
- digi c10 - 22.wav - HORSE - EATING POTATOES
- Digi J1 69 - Elephant playing harmonica
- DW02 - 65.wav - Space Vacuum Cleaner
- DIGI -C-08     51      HYDRAULIC MANURE TRANSPORTER

And greatest of all;

- SI - 6037  Track 51 - 'Timer - Small Timer with Bell End'

Answer (score 0):

- window birds
- corn wind

Answer (score 0):

- etoll
- clix
- blip

Answer (score 0):

A couple weird ones in my library would be:

AMBVietnamFerrelCatsFightNightExt

WALLAProtestMayDayLAMariachi

Answer (score 0):

- Kubah_Chalet_Sunset_CarAlarmCicada (one particular variety of cicada happened to sound very alarm-like)
- NightSafari_BoarGorillas (I never saw them, but it sounded like wild boars fighting with huge grunting apes close by)
- Tiberium_Washing_Machine

I'm also partial to "SCI FI SPACE WIND" in some commercial library or other.  Sounds like a 70s nostalgia synth band.